# why does my nav tabs move on hover? How can i fix it? i want to use css only,

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, hover

I am using bootstrap grid concept. Whenever I hover over my tabs they move so it ends up looking ugly. Also, my text and the small image move ahead.

**I want to fix this using css only**

## This is my html.

```
<section class="col-md-7">
                            <ul class="help-options">
                                <li class="speical-font">Need Help?</li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="red-text"><img src="images/btn_helpIcall.png" class="space" alt="Call Us" />CALL <span class="btn-black-text"> US</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="blue-text"><img src="images/btn_helpIsubmititcket.jpg" alt="Submit Ticket" /> SUBMIT <span class="btn-black-text"> TICKET</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="green-text"><img src="images/btn_helpchat.png" alt="Live Chat" /> LIVE <span class="btn-black-text"> CHAT</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="purple-text"><img src="images/btn_helplearmore.png" alt="Learn More" /> LEARN <span class="btn-black-text"> MORE</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <form class="form-inline">
                                <ul class="search-options" >
                                    <section class="form-group">
                                        <li><label for="person" class="speical-font">Find People:</label>
                                            <input type"text" class="form-control input-box-width" name="person" placeholder="Joe Patric"/> </li>
                                        <li><input name="search" class="form-control input-box-width" placeholder="Search"/><input class="search-btn" /></li>
                                        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-brown">ADVANCED <i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-lg"></i></button></li>
                                    </section>
                                </ul>
                            </form>
                        </section>
```

## CSS code starts here

```
.help-options > li, .search-options > section > li {
    list-style: none;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 5px 5px 0 5px;
    margin: 0;
}
.help-options > li >a > img{
    border-radius: 50%;



}
.space{
    padding-right: 5px;
}
.speical-font {
    font-family: 'Shadows Into Light', cursive;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.purple-text, .blue-text, .red-text, .green-text{
    color: #6d5793;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.blue-text{
    color:#96D1CC;

}


.red-text{
    color:#B1172B;

}
 .red-text > a:hover{
     text-decoration:none;
 }

.green-text{
    color:#ACD275;
}
.btn-black-text {
    color: #000000;
}
.help-options > li > a{

}
.help-options > li:nth-child(2) > a:hover, .help-options > li:nth-child(3) > a:hover, .help-options > li:nth-child(4) > a:hover, .help-options > li:nth-child(5) > a:hover{
    background-color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
   height:34px;
   border-radius:15px;
   -moz-border-radius:15px;
   -webkit-border-radius:15px;
  padding:7px 7px 8px 0;
}
.help-options > li:nth-child(2) > a:hover{
    color:#B1172B;
}
.help-options > li:nth-child(3) > a:hover{
    color:#96D1CC;
}
.help-options > li:nth-child(4) > a:hover{
     color:#ACD275;
}
.help-options > li:nth-child(5) > a:hover{
   color: #6d5793;
}
```

Comment: Can you kindly create a snippet or live demo, please?

Comment: Or if you can give us the url of the original code

Answer (score 1):

Edited Answer:

Keep the padding the same for both normal and hover

```css
 body {
   background: #cfcfcf;
 }
 .help-options > li,
 .search-options > section > li {
   list-style: none;
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 5px 5px 0 5px;
   margin: 0;
 }
 .help-options > li >a > img {
   border-radius: 50%;
 }
 .space {
   padding-right: 5px;
 }
 .speical-font {
   font-family: 'Shadows Into Light', cursive;
   font-weight: 700;
   font-size: 14px;
   letter-spacing: 2px;
 }
 .purple-text,
 .blue-text,
 .red-text,
 .green-text {
   color: #6d5793;
   font-size: 11px;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-weight: 600;
   padding: 7px 7px 8px 0;
 }
 .blue-text {
   color: #96D1CC;
 }
 .red-text {
   color: #B1172B;
 }
 .red-text > a:hover {
   text-decoration: none;
 }
 .green-text {
   color: #ACD275;
 }
 .btn-black-text {
   color: #000000;
 }
 .help-options > li > a {} .help-options > li:nth-child(2) > a:hover,
 .help-options > li:nth-child(3) > a:hover,
 .help-options > li:nth-child(4) > a:hover,
 .help-options > li:nth-child(5) > a:hover {
   background-color: #ffffff;
   text-decoration: none;
   height: 34px;
   border-radius: 15px;
   -moz-border-radius: 15px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
   padding: 7px 7px 8px 0;
 }
 .help-options > li:nth-child(2) > a:hover {
   color: #B1172B;
 }
 .help-options > li:nth-child(3) > a:hover {
   color: #96D1CC;
 }
 .help-options > li:nth-child(4) > a:hover {
   color: #ACD275;
 }
 .help-options > li:nth-child(5) > a:hover {
   color: #6d5793;
 }
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="col-md-7">
  <ul class="help-options">
    <li class="speical-font">Need Help?</li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="red-text">
        <img src="images/btn_helpIcall.png" class="space" alt="Call Us" />CALL <span class="btn-black-text"> US</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="blue-text">
        <img src="images/btn_helpIsubmititcket.jpg" alt="Submit Ticket" />SUBMIT <span class="btn-black-text"> TICKET</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="green-text">
        <img src="images/btn_helpchat.png" alt="Live Chat" />LIVE <span class="btn-black-text"> CHAT</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="purple-text">
        <img src="images/btn_helplearmore.png" alt="Learn More" />LEARN <span class="btn-black-text"> MORE</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <form class="form-inline">
    <ul class="search-options">
      <section class="form-group">
        <li>
          <label for="person" class="speical-font">Find People:</label>
          <input type "text" class="form-control input-box-width" name="person" placeholder="Joe Patric" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <input name="search" class="form-control input-box-width" placeholder="Search" />
          <input class="search-btn" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-brown">ADVANCED <i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-lg"></i>
          </button>
        </li>
      </section>
    </ul>
  </form>
</section>
```

Comment: but if i do that it does not cover the whole thing it just covers the text. i want the hover effect to cover the tiny image as well and match up the height and width of the complete <li>. so is there any other way to do it?

Comment: didnt get you, what covers what?

Comment: as per my posted code the hover effect( which is a white background) covers the whole <li> (that is a tiny img and some text) but when i hover it moves a bit ahead so i want a solution which can make the white background cover the img and the text

Comment: this works but it does not take border radius and space between those tiny image reduces

Comment: You rather hire someone to get this sorted! your initial question was about padding and I helped you with that. SO is about helping you not writing the code for you

Comment: you never gave a correct solution so you better don't say that you partial tried to solve the issue even i am able to resolve it in other way but if i give my hover effect 5px padding on right side it messes up

Comment: all the best @RupaliTanna